# How to generate a URL query string without query attribute values (only it's names)

Tags: html

I'm using a simple HTML form with a GET in the method attribute and I wish to send the form values as a query string without the query attribute values... That's possible?

What I get:

```
http://.../category?mens=on&narrow=on
```

What I need:

```
http://.../category?mens&narrow
```

I'm using check-boxes as input fields.

Thank's in advance for any hint!

Comment: Do you only want to send them if they're checked?

Comment: How are you constructing these URLs?

Comment: Yep, the idea is to send only the checked ones, and remove that value overhead to keep the query string small (I just check for get variable keys in a server side script).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a form's default submit URL. You might just want to redirect to a URL you make yourself (or do an AJAX call).

HTML:

```
<button type='submit' onclick='submit()'Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
// checkbox form elements
var mensCheckboxElement, narrowCheckboxElement, ...;

// simulate form submit
function submit() {
  var checkedBoxes = [];
  if(mensCheckboxElement.checked) checkedBoxes.push('mens');
  if(narrowCheckedboxElement.checked) checkedBoxes.push('narrow');
  // et cetera. This is just to give you an idea,
  // but there are definitely better ways to do this

  // custom url without values
  var submitUrl = '/category?'+ checkedBoxes.join('&');

  // redirect to submitUrl or make an ajax call

  // prevent normal form submit
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we can add JS based listeners to trigger a url with a parsed query string. But by now I'm just wondering if we don't have anything more cleaner.

Comment: @aamuller Afaik that's the best we can do. I'm not sure how common the specific format you asked for is.